# Selection sort using pointers C with a structure

Tags: c, sorting, struct, selection

I left out main but basically this should sort 8 elements but when I compile it, it says:

```
prelab3.c: In function ‘sort’:
prelab3.c:77: error: invalid operands to binary > (have ‘DynamicArray’ and ‘DynamicArray’)
```

and I'm not sure why exactly, can you not compare things in a struct using pointers?

Code below:

```
    typedef struct Array_
        {
            int data;
    }DynamicArray;


    void sort(DynamicArray *v, unsigned int size)
    {
        int i, j;
        int min;
        DynamicArray temp;
        for (i=0; i<size-1; i++)
        {
            min = i;
            for(j=i+1; j<size; j++)
            {
                if(*(v+i) > *(v+j))
                {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            if(min != i)
            {
                temp = *v;
                *v = *(v+min);
                *(v+min) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing structs is meaningless but you could compare the integers inside them.  Try this:

```
(v+i)->data > (v+j)->data
```

Comment: Yes now it compiles! Thanks! Now I have to figure out the logic, its not sorting right.

Answer (score 0):

As @David said, you can't compare structs. Your algorithm have some mistakes too:

- The j loop is intended to find the minimum item in the range [i,size), so your comparison must be against the minimum so far found:

  ```
  (v+min)->data > (v+j)->data
  ```

  I recommend you to use the array notation, in my opinion is clearer:

  ```
  v[min].data > v[j].data
  ```
- The last part (after the min != i comparison) is intended to exchange the values between the min and i positions, so your code should look something like:

  ```
  temp = v[i];
  v[i] = v[min];
  v[min] = temp;
  ```

Finally, keep in mind that struct assignment not always work, for more complex structs than yours, you might need to use field by field assignment, or memcpy().

Comment: I'm not sure that you can use v[min].data with v being a pointer...think you have to use -> instead like (v+min)->data.

Comment: @Survaf93 the C subscript operator [] is intended to be used with any non-void pointer expression. An array variable is just a particular case where the name of the array is a constant pointer.

Comment: My mistake I ment the dot '.', think you need to have v[min]->data instead of v[min].data

Comment: OK. When using v[min] the result is the content of the min position, not the address of that element, that's why I use dot instead ->. A simpler example with an integer array, A[i] give you the integer value in the i-st position of A, but (A+i) give you the address of this element, so you have to use *(A+i) to get the integer value.